# Facebook Does Not Recognize Custom Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-ios-sdk

A user shares memes from the iOS app.

But Facebook always says "SomePerson shared a link via AppName"

I'd like it to recognize, the meme custom object that I have made.

i.e. "SomePerson shared a meme via AppName"

I am using the og meta tags in the link, and according to Facebook's Open Graph debugger, my webpages are fine.

**So then why doesn't it say meme instead of link? And how can I achieve this behaviour? Do I have to do something on the iOS client side?**

I am using the following iOS method to share memes by the way

```
  [FBRequestConnection
     startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
     parameters:someParameters
     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
     completionHandler:someHandler];
```

I also tried creating objects directly from the device instead of from the web link meta tags, using the sample code that Facebook provided, but I kept getting errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think me/feed only shares "links" and do not recognize the open graph types. You can create your own open graph actions/objects (likely with very little change to your server side since you're already serving up the meta tags) to create custom stories.

Comment: Thanks @MingLi , that was helpful, I have created custom objects on Facebook's App Dashboard, do you know how I can call them from iOS?

Comment: Check out the Scrumptious or RPS sample app on how we use open graph objects and actions.

Comment: @MingLi Can you please do me a favour and help me out with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310102/facebook-request-never-gets-executed  Basically my FBRequests are not getting sent, so I was wondering if you might know what i might be doing wrong. Thanks!