# Facebook Request Never Gets Executed

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to get a user's Facebook Friends who also use the same app.

> "Time to get other friends that use this app" always prints out

But neither the result, nor the error are printed

I checked the graph path with Facebook's Graph API explorer, and it worked,  but it does not work with my app for some reason.

```
- (void)getFriendsForUser:(NSNotification *)notification {
    GGUser *theCurrentUser = [notification object];
    NSLog(@"Time to get other friends that use this app");
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=id,name,installed,picture" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"result %@",result);
        NSLog(@"error - %@", error);            
    }];
}
```

Other FBRequests, like with a graph path of @"me", work, just not this one. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are not passing the token that's why the request itself is not getting executed:

Do this:

```
FBRequest *facebookReq =  [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=id,name,installed,picture"];

[facebookReq setSession:FBSession.activeSession];

[facebookReq startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"result %@",result);

    NSLog(@"error %@",error);

}];
```

Let me know if it doesn't work. :)

Cheers

Comment: This looks like it should work, and it probably will work for most people, but unfortunately does not work for my app, I'm not sure what's going wrong with it, but this code looks right. +1 for effort! But no checkmark unfortunately since it doesn't work for my app.

Comment: Do you have the token with you? Are you using FBSessions in your app?

Comment: Yes. I followed all the instructions given in the Facebook SDK.

Comment: Try and switch to latest SDK 3.7.1, it could be internal bug, switching to new sdk should prevail this random stuff.

Comment: It's working about 40% of the time, so not very reliably, I am kind of confused as to what's going wrong, thanks for your effort though!

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you're putting request parameters into the path.

Try using just @"me/friends" as the path, and @{ @"fields", @"id,name,installed,picture" } as the parameters.

Comment: There are no errors printed in the times that it doesn't work?

Comment: Nope, no errors, the FBRequest never occurs or at least it never reaches the completion block, what may be stopping it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do just fine. But make sure you are executing it **on the main thread**.

It looks like not every thread is usable for FBRequest. I am personally had issues starting requests from Core Data context's thread.

```
NSString* path = @"me/friends?fields=id,name,installed,picture";
FBRequest* req = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:[FBSession activeSession]
                                          graphPath:path];
[req startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection* connection,
                                  NSDictionary<FBGraphObject>* result,
                                  NSError* error)
{
    NSLog(@"result %@",result);
    NSLog(@"error %@",error);
}
```